# How to load mapbox-gl-js with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mapbox-gl-js

For a project, I have to use RequireJS to load mapbox-gl-js library. However, it does not work and I always get the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

This is my RequireJS Code:

```
requirejs.config({  
    {   
        ...
        'leaflet-mapbox-gl': 'js/leaflet-mapbox-gl',
        'mapbox-gl': 'js/mapbox-gl'  
    }
```

I want to use it together with leaflet-mapbox-gl. Without RequireJS everything works but is obviously not what I want. I also tried the following shim configuration without success:

```
shim : {
    'mapbox-gl': {
        exports: ['mapboxgl']
    }
    'leaflet-mapbox-gl': {
        deps: ['leaflet','mapbox-gl']
    }
}
```

How do I load mapbox-gl-js correctly with RequireJS?

Comment: I have never used RequireJS, but looking at the examples in the doc, `exports` always seems to be a string, not an array of strings. Maybe: `exports: 'mapboxgl'` ?

Comment: Thanks Steve. Unfortunately, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. Problem wasn't mapbox-gl-js but rather leaflet-mapbox-gl. Had to wrap the following code around leaflet-mapbox-gl to make it work with RequireJS:

```
(function (factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module depending on mapboxgl.
    define(['mapboxgl'], factory);
} else {
    // No AMD.
    factory(mapboxgl);
}
}(function (mapboxgl) {
//...original leaflet-mapbox-gl code
}));
```

This is my shim configuration:

```
    shim :
    {
        // other code ...
        'mapboxgl' : {
            exports: 'mapboxgl'
        },
        'leaflet-mapbox-gl': {
            deps: ['leaflet','mapboxgl']
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else